# Filtering through an array after a GET method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

guys can you explain why is it not working?

I am GETTING an array from my backend rails API which gives me the data correctly.
Now i made an empty array where i filter  my records based on their ID.

It does it correctly ,but whenever i refresh my page  my filterRecords methods is not calling  it just gives me an empty array.

Here i am looping through that array and writing out the description in my filteredRecords:

```
<h1
          class="content"
          v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
          :key="index"
          :record="record"
          :class="{ 'is-active': index === activeSpan }"
        >
          
          <strong>{{ record.description }} </strong>
        </h1>
```

This is my filterRecords() in computed:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      id: "id"
    }),
    
    filteredRecords() {
      return this.records.filter(record => {
        return record.template_id === this.id;
      });
    }
  },
```

this is how i am getting the data from an API:

```
created() {
    
    if (!localStorage.signedIn) {
      this.$router.replace("/");
    } else {
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/records")
        .then(response => {
          this.records = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
      
    }
  },
```

So how do i make this work so that when i reload my page it gets the records   and after that  it filters through it ( calls the filteredRecords computedmethod)

Thank you!

**EDIT**

hello problem was that i used   return record.template_id === this.id;

and it should be just return record.template_id **==** this.id;

**since they are different data types.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code once

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      id: "id"
    }),
    
    filteredRecords: function () {
      let localId = this.id;
      let filtered = this.records.filter(record => {
        return record.template_id == localId;
      });
      console.log(localId);
      console.log(filtered);
      return filtered;
    }
  },
```

If this does not work, can you log 'this.id' and see what is getting logged.

Comment: hello the this.id works it  logs out the correct ID    i got this id from mapgetters (vuex)

however we still couldnt find the solution.

Comment: Did you try the above approach?

Comment: I have made a few changes to the above logic, can you try that once.

Comment: Hello i copied that,   now it console logs the correct ID and console logs an empty array .

Comment: Can you also log console.log(this.records)? and see if there are any records with that id?

Comment: @endoftheworld was able to solve the problem, the issue was '===' the id and template_id were both of different data type

Answer (score 1):

It happens because overwriting values of array are not reactive. So Vue doesn't detect the change and doesn't call your computed property.
Try this:

```js
this.records.splice(0, this.records.length - 1, ...response.data)
```

More about this you can read here: [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

> `.splice` will work because Vue wraps this method and do some magic under the hood

**Edit 1**

```js
for(let i = 0; i < response.data - 1; i++) {
  Vue.set(this.records, i, response.data[i]);
}
```

**Edit 2**

After discussion via chat we figured out that there is a second problem with types (id of the element returned from backend is a string and localId is a number so `.filter` will return an empty array). The solution is to use `==` over `===`, but I would suggest to use:

```js
 record.template_id.toString() === this.id.toString()
```

Then we will be sure that both id's are strings

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but where should i implement this code? to my GET method? because if so it is still not calling it after a reload .

Comment: Inside `created` hook. You should replace `this.records = response.data;` with this  `this.records.splice(0, this.records.length - 1, ...response.data)`

Comment: hello yes i did that but its not calling it either unfortunately. When i reload the page its just gone its not doing the filterrecords computed method.

Comment: Are you sure that `response.data` is not empty ? Can you check this ?

Comment: Yes i immediately log it out and i get back the data its  not empty.

Comment: Try to use this **Edit 1** to replace `this.records = response.data;`. Let me know if this works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219175/discussion-between-endoftheworld-and-krzysztof-kaczynski).